# iphone index of array with dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

i have an array with dictionaries,

. how to get the index for a specific dictionary... [where I got the data for the dictionary i want to find, but need the index is on]

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictois = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictois setObject:@"easySpritedd" forKey:@"Nombre"];
[dictois setObject:@"X" forKey:@"290"];
[dictois setObject:@"Y" forKey:@"300"];

int fooIndex = [self.bloquesArray indexOfObject: dictois];
```

but as you see i dont know yet how to get the dictionary for comparing in the indexOfObject

thanks!

Comment: Don't use `new`. Use `alloc` and `init` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSDictionary objects have the following comparison methods:

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary
```

With the following discussion

> Two dictionaries have equal contents if they each hold the same number
>   of entries and, for a given key, the corresponding value objects in
>   each dictionary satisfy the isEqual: test.

This should be the case for you. Sadly you cannot change the method which NSArray uses to calculate the indexOfObject: so it can't help you, hence the solution provided by Denis is the best I can think of (unless you fancy subclassing NSArray which I wouldn't recommend).

---

Just as a complement to Denis' answer you could use the NSArray method

```
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

instead of

```
- (NSUInteger)indexOfObjectPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

If having several equal objects in the array is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictois = [[NSMutableDictionary new]autorelease];

[dictois setObject:@"easySpritedd" forKey:@"Nombre"];
[dictois setObject:@"X" forKey:@"290"];
[dictois setObject:@"Y" forKey:@"300"];

int fooIndex = [self.bloquesArray indexOfObjectPassingTest: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
  if( [[obj class] isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]] ) {
    BOOL result = [obj isEqualToDictionary: diction];
    *stop = result;
    return result;
  }

  *stop = NO;
  return NO;

}];
```

Comment: hi, thanks, when I log the fooIndex                     NSLog(@"resultadoxx ::%d", fooIndex);
I get:: 2147483647 ,,, but i know the wanted dictionary is in index 0,

Comment: can you add an nslog() inside comparing block, that will print out compared object and post the logs here?

Comment: i've put out the full code for solution and got no accept... just great :/